# Cross Domain AJAX Post using easyXdm

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cross-domain, cross-domain-policy, easyxdm

I am trying to get a cross domain AJAX post to work using the easyXdm library.

In my local development environment I have two sites:

```
1. http://localhost/MySite/ws/easyXDM/cors/index.html (EasyXdm file)
2. http://localhost/MyClientSite/TestPage.html (AJAX post from here)
```

**TestPage.html (AJAX Post)**

```
var rpc = new easyXDM.Rpc({
        remote: "http://localhost/MySite/ws/easyXDM/cors/index.html"
    },
    {
        remote: {
            request: {}
        }
    });

rpc.request({
        url: "http://localhost/MySite/ws/MyService.asmx/DoSomething",
        method: "POST",
        data: jsonData
    }, function(response) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(response.data));

        $('#thanksDiv').fadeIn(2000, function () {
            $('#thanksDiv').fadeOut(4000);
        });
    });
```

When I do the AJAX post I get the following in my browser's console:

```
easyXDM present on 'http://localhost/MySite/ws/easyXDM/cors/index.html?xdm_e=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2FMyClientSite%2FTestPage.html&xdm_c=default884&xdm_p=4 
native JSON found 
easyXDM.Rpc: constructor 
{Private}: preparing transport stack 
{Private}: using parameters from query 
easyXDM.stack.SameOriginTransport: constructor 
easyXDM.stack.QueueBehavior: constructor 
easyXDM.stack.RpcBehavior: init 
{Private}: firing dom_onReady 
... deferred messages ... 
easyXDM.Rpc: constructor 
{Private}: preparing transport stack 
{Private}: using parameters from query 
easyXDM.stack.SameOriginTransport: constructor 
easyXDM.stack.QueueBehavior: constructor 
easyXDM.stack.RpcBehavior: init 
... end of deferred messages ... 
easyXDM.stack.SameOriginTransport: init 
easyXDM.stack.RpcBehavior: received request to execute method request using callback id 1 
easyXDM.stack.RpcBehavior: requested to execute procedure request 
easyXDM.stack.QueueBehavior: removing myself from the stack
```

**Problem:** The web service never actually receives the data. This is obvious as my AJAX post success function should show a `thanksDiv` and also a record should be created in the *database.

**Note:** I am replacing my existing AJAX post code as I need to use easyXdm to overcome an issue with Internet Explorer 6 and 7 on a client's site.

**Additional Information:**
The file-structure where my easyXdm files are located is as follows:

```
/ws/easyXDM/easyXDM.debug.js
/ws/easyXDM/easyXdm.swf
/ws/easyXDM/json2.js 
/ws/easyXDM/name.html
/ws/easyXDM/cors/index.html
```

Comment: there is so few people that have worked with easyXDM. May you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27203172/easyxdm-download-files-from-3rd-party-service please?

Comment: @V_B Both client and server must be using EasyXDM in order for it to work successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My web service was throwing a HTTP 500 server error as jsonData was not being sent correctly via easyXdm.

The json data looks like this before it was posted:

> { "param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"...... }

However, the web service was receiving the data one character per line e.g.

```
{
"
p
a
r
a
m
"
....
```

I was not serialising the json data prior to my post. So, based on the original code I posted in the original question:

To get it working I changed the line

```
data: jsonData
```

to

```
data: JSON.parse(jsonData)
```