# EasyXDM: download files from 3rd party service

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, easyxdm

I want to make JavaScript cross domain request to 3rd party server. I've read about [easyXDM](https://github.com/oyvindkinsey/easyXDM#readme) but still can't finally figure out how does it work. I tried their [example](http://consumer.easyxdm.net/current/example/upload.html) in Chrome but it doesn't work for me (`Entity to Large` for music and `Not Allowed` for text files).

**Question:** *Is easyXDM appropriate for my needs?* I still don't understand whether it's possible to download smth from 3rd party service/domain

Comment: easyXDM is used for cross domain requests from server to browser.  Without knowing more about what you are trying to accomplish, its not possible to tell you if its right for your needs.

Comment: The 3th party server must allow you to get his content due to origin restriction. This server may implement easyXDM or just add the correct header to each requests. If the 3th party server does not implement anything, you may just not include his content. I suggest you to make the test with your own server and ensure you allow CORD, then you may change to a real 3th party server or ask to them if they do not implement it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless the third-party server you are communicating **specifically** supports EasyXDM, it is not appropriate. EasyXDM requires that both sides be using it; it cannot be used to communicate with a service that isn't using it.